# What reference to the sheet I should use in google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function in the .gs file:

```
function DayMacros() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<some_id>");
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('<sheet_name>');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var source = sheet.getRange('A'+ lastrow +':G'+ lastrow)
  source.autoFill(sheet.getRange('A'+ lastrow +':G'+ (lastrow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
};
```

The purpose of this function is to add 1 row to the table. And I have a trigger that invokes this function every day. My question is: "Is this the right way to reference the sheet?". Maybe I can get it somehow in function because it is recorded as a macro for the sheet. I tried to use the `.getActive()` method of `SpreadsheetApp`, but it occurred that when the trigger works, no spreadsheet is activated, so it simply returns `NULL`.

Comment: Is this script bound to a Google Sheet or is it a standalone script?

Comment: @LorenaGomez It's bound to the Google sheet.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74931048/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script is bounded to a Google Spreadsheet, then you can use the following:

```
function DayMacros() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('<sheet_name>');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var source = sheet.getRange('A'+ lastrow +':G'+ lastrow)
  source.autoFill(sheet.getRange('A'+ lastrow +':G'+ (lastrow + 1)), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
};
```

If you're working with a different Google Spreadsheet or with a standalone script, then you can use the script you posted in your question.

**References:**

[getActive()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactive)

[openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

This `SpreadsheetApp.openById("<some_id>");` returns an object of [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet) and this `sheet.getSheetByName('<sheet_name>')` returns an object of [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).